# Errno 22 when loading image

Tags: python, neural-network, argparse, pytorch

I am having trouble opening an image with the neural_style script found [here](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/tree/master/fast_neural_style). When passing arguments to the script in Spyder's IPython console, I have continually received the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:'<C:/Users/Caleb/Documents/Python_Scripts/pytorch/project1/content_images/20180727_201120.jpg>'
```

I have attempted changing forward slashes to backslashes, using a filepath that starts at my working directory (not including the folders above it), and eliminating the filepath from the entry (i.e. simply entering the filename). None of these fixes have solved my problem. The arguments follow the form:

```
python neural_style/neural_style.py eval \
    --content-image </path/to/content/image> \
    --model </path/to/saved/model> \
    --output-image </path/to/output/image> \
    --cuda 1
```

What amendments must I make to my arguments to no longer receive this error? I am using Windows 10 and Python 3.6.5. The arguments are read by argparse.

Please note that I used () instead of <> above, not sure how to properly use <> without deleting the interior content.

Thank you!

Comment: Note that there are parentheses around your path; that doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: "Please note that I used () instead of <> above": ah: those `<>` in examples represent placeholders, to indicate the actual value should be changed, *and* the `<>` discarded. You certainly *cannot* replace them by parentheses at will. Instead, ignore the `<>`, use the correct file name, and certainly don't use `()`.

Comment: I may have misinterpreted that statement on `<>`. If it's about formatting on StackOverflow: use a code-block (also for error traces): quotes are really bad for anything that resembles code. code blocks leave the `<>` alone. See my edit once approved.

Comment: But since you still have `()` around your path in the error message, that means you're actually still passing `(....)` as an argument. So I'm guessing you made a mistake running the script, *and* had trouble formatting your question. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are right that I trouble formatting my question. I will go back and edit my question to reflect your advice. I had no idea that those brackets represented placeholders-- that obviously solves my problem and I'm sure will help me avert many more in the future. I feel quite silly now! But it is better that my oversight was corrected now than any later time. Thank you for your help!